# Elegant way to retrieve all x-coordinates

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a set of points declared in a Cartesian coordinate system:

```
points = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Does there exist an elegant way to get get all the x-coordinates as a list in `points`?

The following is what I've done to retrieve all the x-coordinates and return them as a list:

```
def getXs(points):
    length = len(points)
    xs = [None] * length
    for i in range(length):
        xs[i] = points[i][0]
    return xs
```

I wish `getXs()` could be shorter and more elegant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
x_values=[i[0] for i in points]
```